# Does anyone have a example of Dual Contouring in C#?

Tags: unity, c#, terrain, octree

I'm trying to develop a method of creating terrain using Perlin. I've followed plenty of the Minecraft tutorials, and got them to function. I've done some playing around with MarchingSquares, but I'm not digging it.
Now, I've been trying to create a method of dual contouring, and I'm also trying to get the concept of Octrees down at the same time. I used to segment my array of data in small chunkes, but the whole Collapsing and making a larger "chunk" function like a smaller chunker is just not regiserting.

I was hoping someone can share some C# code, preferably for Unity but really just something for me to try to pick apart to understand would help.

When it really comes down to it, I'm not trying to make a game where different "voxels" aren't different types of blocks, just represent where dirt is and where dirt isn't. In game, I want dirt to be taken away due to explosions, but not have a method of placing dirt. I'd like this effect for large enclosed game levels.

Any comments or advice are appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure if your question could fit this site's requirements as it seems to me in "how to get started" format. By the way with [a really rapid serach](https://www.google.it/search?q=dual+contouring+c%23&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=IAy6V_WAE_SP8QfJx4fYBA) I found [this](https://github.com/tuckbone/DualContouringCSharp). Hope it helps

Comment: I don't know how after all the searches on several engines I didn't get this link. Thank you.